# How to hide the "Contents" header in the pdf output

Tags: org-mode, latex, pdf, latex-header

Every time I would export the org doc as a PDF I would get this random "Contents" tag before the table and I am not sure how to remove it.

I attached below an image of what I mean

There's probably a header for it but I am not aware of it

```
#+title: Test
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[fontsize=12pt]{scrextend}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{helvet} \renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[margin=1.15in]{geometry}

| wd      | wdwd    | wdwd  | wd wad | dwd     |
|---------+---------+-------+--------+---------|
| 4154    | 454     | 4545  | 65416  | 6546    |
| 65465   | 654654  | 6584  | 654654 | 654654  |
| 654     | 456     | 454   | uhio   | ohb     |
| oouj    | ouho    | oubob | oiuhoh | oiuhoh  |
| oihoh   | oihoiuh | opih  | poihh  | poihpih |
| poihpih | ohub    | pihp  | pihpi  | pihhi   |
```

[image: output pdf]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the heading for the table of contents which is added by default. You don't have any contents because you have no headlines in this file: try adding a `* My table` headline and see what you get then.

If you don't want the TOC at all, add an `#+OPTIONS` line:

```
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil
```

at the top of your file. See [Export Settings](https://orgmode.org/manual/Export-Settings.html) in the manual.

Comment: Did you try this? Did it work?

Comment: this worked perfectly thank you